# No such snippet is present in configuration warning

Tags: java, javadoc, asciidoc, spring-restdocs

I'm doing documentation using Spring rest auto docs and AsciiDoc. Below is my error message

## Error Message

```
Section snippet 'auto-method-path' is configured to be included in the section but no such snippet is present in configuration

Section snippet 'auto-description' is configured to be included in the section but no such snippet is present in configuration
```

The auto-method-path is being generated so I have no idea where the warning comes from. But the auto-description is according to the documentation, the javaDoc of the controller so I have no idea why is this documentation not being generated.

## JavaDoc

```
/**
   * Returns a Customer
   *
   * @param id       the id of the customer
   * @return the customer
   */
  @GetMapping(path = "api/customer/{id}", produces = HAL_JSON_VALUE)
```

Comment: did you forget to close your path string with a double quote?

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli Just here on stack overflow! I rewrote the path manually because the original one contained my company name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed. I Was Missing this on my Pom :

```
   <execution>
            <id>generate-javadoc-json</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>javadoc-no-fork</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <doclet>capital.scalable.restdocs.jsondoclet.ExtractDocumentationAsJsonDoclet</doclet>
              <docletArtifact>
                <groupId>capital.scalable</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-auto-restdocs-json-doclet</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.9</version>
              </docletArtifact>
              <destDir>generated-javadoc-json</destDir>
              <reportOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</reportOutputDirectory>
              <useStandardDocletOptions>false</useStandardDocletOptions>
              <show>package</show>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `SnippetRegistry.AUTO_METHOD_PATH` and `SnippetRegistry.AUTO_DESCRIPTION` from your AutoDocumentation.sectionBuilder().snippetNames(...)

```java
// from
AutoDocumentation.sectionBuilder().snippetNames(
                    AUTO_METHOD_PATH,
                    AUTO_DESCRIPTION,
                    AUTO_AUTHORIZATION,
                    ...
                    ).build();

// to
AutoDocumentation.sectionBuilder().snippetNames(
                    AUTO_AUTHORIZATION,
                    ...
                    ).build();
```